# on reductive monoids which are gorenstein

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory, singularity-theory, semigroups-and-monoids

Let $M$ a reductive monoid, i.e. a integral normal affine scheme, which is a monoid whose group of units is a connected reductive group.

By Rittatore http://www.cmat.edu.uy/cmat/docentes/alvaro/publicaciones/pdfs/cohen.pdf,
 we know that they're all Cohen-Macaulay.

Do we know which of them are Gorenstein?

For example, is Vinberg's monoid (aka envelopping semigroup) Gorenstein, or at least the toric variety associated to it?